# Blazored Typeahead SearchMethod has the wrong return type

Tags: blazor, typeahead, blazored

I'm trying to use blazored typeahed for my app but there seems to be a problem with the search method.

Here is my current code:

```
<BlazoredTypeaheadInput SearchMethod="Search"
                   @bind-Value="Value"
                   Placeholder="@Resources.SelectVehicle.SearchByLicensePlateNumber"
                   MinimumLength="3"
                   Debounce="500">

</BlazoredTypeaheadInput>


@code {
    private Vehicle _value;

    private async Task<List<Vehicle>> Search(string searchText)
    {
        var request = new SERVICES.FindVehiclesRequest()
        {
            LicensePlateNumber = searchText,
        };

        string[] ids = await VehicleService.FindVehicles(request);

        SERVICES.VehicleItem[] vehicles = await VehicleService.GetVehicles(ids.Take(5));
        List<Vehicle> result = vehicles
             .Select(Convert)
             .ToList();

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

Apparently, there's a mistake in the Search method as I get this error - 'Task> __generated__SelectVehicle.Search(string)' has the wrong return type'
I've tried to return just `return result;` but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try returning `Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>>`  from your search method?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SearchMethod` Parameter on this component expects a return type of `IEnumerable<T>` inside a Task, so your method signature needs to be

`private async Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> Search(string searchText)`